# How do i solve this graph theory problem?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

"A sheet has a height (h) of at least 2 and a width (w) of at least 2. There are (w)x(h) tiles on the sheet. A valid path is one that moves adjacent to the current tile (forward, backwards, left, right, but not diagonal). Show that if either w or h is an even number, then there exists a path (P) that touches every single tile exactly once and ends up at the same tile it started at. Then prove that if both w or h is odd, then this path (P) can not exist."

I'm stumped. I'm not sure how to prove this. I have drawn it out and can see that it holds, but i'm not sure how to prove it generally for any number of w and h. We are told not to use induction on this question, and that was the only method i was thinking could work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: When at least one of $w$ and $h$ is even, there is a systematic way to traverse the sheet; try to generalize from this example, in which the bullet points represent square of the sheet.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\bullet&\to&\bullet&\to&\bullet&\to&\bullet\\
\uparrow&&&&&&\downarrow\\
\bullet&&\bullet&\leftarrow&\bullet&&\bullet\\
\uparrow&&\downarrow&&\uparrow&&\downarrow\\
\bullet&\leftarrow&\bullet&&\bullet&\leftarrow&\bullet\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

For the odd case, imagine coloring the squares alternately black and white, like a checkerboard. Each move must go from a square to a square of the other color. If $w$ and $h$ are both odd, and the square in the upper lefthand corner is white, how many white squares are there? How many black squares?

Comment: Would it be because the sheet can be broken down into smaller 2x2 graphs?    For the odd case would there be wh/2 white squares?

Comment: @Team.Coco: No, because the traversal is possible even when only *one* of the dimensions is even. The route that I used in the $3\times 4$ example above really does generalize to all sheets with at least one even dimension. Try it first with even widths: start in the upper lefthand corner, go across the top, and then try to generalize what I did. When you have that down, you can go to even heights; that requires turning the pattern sideways.

Comment: Hmmm. Is that path the ONLY path that could exist for that certain grid? I am having trouble coming up with another. The reason i am having trouble generalizing is because that certain path doesnt exist in a 2x2 grid. Im not sure how to apply that to EVERY grid possible

Comment: @Team.Coco: The case in which one dimension is $2$ is a special case that has to be handled separately, but it’s also completely trivial, since you can simply loop around the sheet. What I did generalizes to all sheets with an even dimension $\ge 4$.

Comment: Thank you. I think i'll be able to solve it now with what you told me. I will mark this as answered, but i might ask a question later tonight if you are still around.

Comment: @Team.Coco: You’re welcome. I’ll be in and out, but if you do leave a question, I will eventually see it.

Comment: By hte way, congrats Brian onreaching 400k! its a shame that nobody has congratulated you on meta... but thanks for your clear exposition on your answers. This site wouldnt be the same without you!

Comment: @ILoveMath: Thanks! That’s okay; I don’t think that anyone congratulated André on reaching 400k, either.

Comment: Hey Brian, the assignment was turned in. Do you mind sharing what you would have put for the proof? I want to make sure i understand it

Comment: @Team.Coco: For the odd/odd case I’d observe that a tour that visits each square exactly once requires an odd number of steps. Each step involves a move to a square of the other color, so if I start on a white square, after an odd number of steps I must be on a black square: every second step puts me back on a white square, and the odd step at the end leaves me on a black square. That means that the tour cannot end where it began. (I could phrase it in more graph-theoretic terms, if that were more appropriate for the course.)

Comment: So this is what i got. Let me know if it is a correct answer. The generalization is that if there is a dimension of 2, then you can simply start at any point and move in a rectangular/square shape. If there is an even greater than 2, then you can start at the top left, traverse the width, then traverse the height. Then go 1 unit width left at a time and then go up w-1, then go left then go down w-1 until you reach the left edge in which you can go back up to where you started. I know

Comment: How would you have answered it, since it asked to "Show if either w or h is even then a path exists." and Also "Prove that if both are odd, then there doesnt exist." Is there an easy way to prove/sum it up?

Comment: In other words, how can i prove or state that the figure above holds for all sheets with an even dimension?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  Should i have used induction?

Comment: @Team.Coco: Label the square in row $r$ column $c$ with the ordered pair $\langle r,c\rangle$.  If a tour is possible, we can choose any square as starting point, so I will choose $\langle 1,1\rangle$. If $w=2$, I simply circle the sheet: $\langle 1,1\rangle$ to $\langle 1,2\rangle$, then $\langle k\rangle,2$ to $\langle k+1,2\rangle$ for $k=1,\ldots,h-1$, then $\langle h,2\rangle$ to $\langle h,1\rangle$, then $\langle k,1\rangle$ to $\langle k-1,1\rangle$ for $k=h,h-1,\ldots,2$. If $h=2$ just rotate the sheet $90$° and proceed as before.  If $w\ge 4$ is even, start by going across the ...

Comment: ... first row: $\langle 1,k\rangle$ to $\langle 1,k+1\rangle$ for $k=1,\ldots,w-1$. Then go down the last column: $\langle k,w\rangle$ to $\langle k+1,w\rangle$ for $k=1,\ldots,h-1$. Then $\langle h,w\rangle$ to $\langle h,w-1\rangle$ and up column $w-1$ to the second row: $\langle k,w-1\rangle$ to $\langle k-1,w-1\rangle$ for $k=h,h-1,\ldots,3$. Then $\langle 2,w-1\rangle$ to $\langle w,w-2\rangle$ and back down column $w-2$. Since $w$ is even, the tour is going down the even-numbered columns and up the odd-numbered columns, so it will end with $\langle h,2\rangle$ to $\langle h,1\rangle$ ...

Comment: ... followed by $\langle k,1\rangle$ to $\langle k-1,1\rangle$ for $k=h,h-1,\ldots,2$, ending back at $\langle 1,1\rangle$. It’s possible to add even more detail if it’s likely to be wanted. For instance, we can actually describe every step: if $2<r<h$ and $1\le c\le w$, the step out of $\langle r,c\rangle$ is to $\langle r+1,c\rangle$ if $c$ is even and to $\langle r-1,c\rangle$ if $c$ is odd; if $1\le c<w$, the step out of $\langle r,c\rangle$ is to $\langle r,c+1\rangle$; the step out of $\langle 1,w\rangle$ is to $\langle 2,w\rangle$; if $1\le c\le w$, the step out of ...

Comment: ... $\langle h,c\rangle$ is to $\langle h,c-1\rangle$ if $c$ is even and to $\langle h-1,c\rangle$ if $c$ is odd; and if $1<c<w$, the step out of $\langle 2,c\rangle$ is to $\langle 2,c-1\rangle$ if $c$ is odd and to $\langle 3,c\rangle$ if $c$ is even. Finally, the step out of $\langle 2,1\rangle$ is to $\langle 1,1\rangle$. If $w$ is odd, and $h\ge 4$ is even, just rotate the sheet $90$° and proceed as in the previous case.

Comment: The informal answer in your comment is would probably get $7$ out of $10$ from me. The problem isn’t the informality: frankly, that kind of description is actually easier to follow than what I just did in the previous comments, especially if accompanied by a diagram like the only in my answer. What it’s missing is a clear statement of why it matters that $w$ is even: you need to say that you’re going down the even-numbered columns and up the odd-numbered columns, so that you end up going up the first column and landing back at your starting point.

Comment: You're so awesome. I wish i could give you 1000 points or something for helping me understand this.

Comment: @Team.Coco: Thanks! I’m just very happy when people do catch on.