# Proving bipartite graph properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Fix a board where the height and width are greater than 2. A valid walk on a board is to start on one square and move to a vertically or horizontally adjacent square, so diagonal traversals are not allowed. A tour is a valid walk such that each square is touched exactly once and the walk begins and ends on the same square. Prove that if either the height or width is even, a tour exists. Also prove that if p and q are odd, there is no tour.

First, I prove that this "board" is merely a bipartite graph. Let $V_{i,j}$ be a cell on the graph where $i,j \ge 0$ and $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. If $i$ is even and $j$ is even, color the cell $c_1$. If $i$ is even and $j$ is odd, color the cell $c_2$. If $i$ is odd and $j$ is odd, then color the cell $c_1$. If $i$ is odd and $j$ is even, color the cell $c_2$. Note that the board is two-colored, which is a bipartite graph.

Claim 2: If the height and width are odd, a tour doesn't exist.

1. Assume by contradiction that a tour exists.
2. If the height and width are both odd, the total number of cells (or vertices) is also odd.
3. A tour on a graph of odd vertices would be of odd-length.
4. This is a contradiction because bipartite graphs only contain even-length cycles, so such a tour cannot exist.

I'm unsure of a couple of things, which I hope someone can clear up:

1. Am I interpreting this question right by converting it into a bipartite graph?
2. Is the proof for Claim 2 correct? If not, how can I optimize it?
3. How would I approach proving Claim 1? I was thinking that if there are an even number of vertices in the graph and the two bipartitions have an equal number of vertices in them, a tour might exist. However, I'm not sure how to formulate this into better words.

Comment: What you’ve done so far is fine. For the rest, see my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986460/how-do-i-solve-this-graph-theory-problem).

Comment: The coloring can be used to demonstrate that this board can be regarded as a bipartite graph, and you have used that to good effect to prove the second statement. For the first statement, you might be able to simply demonstrate how to construct a valid tour.

Comment: There is a closely related "weaker" version of this problem that might give some insights.  If you have a "tour" on the board, your bipartite property amounts to coloring it as a checkerboard.  This [older Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112937/proof-for-domino-tiling-over-m-times-n-checkerboard) "Proof for domino tiling over $m\times n$ checkerboard" deals with breaking that tour up into consecutive pairs of squares along that tour.